# Foreign key collection is null

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, entity-framework-core

So, I was trying to get something with EF core. I'm doing code-first as it's best for me (I prefer it also cause no database has to  be provided for users). Anyways, I'm going to have a big database with loads of relations, so I have to use foreign keys.

However, the foreign key collection is always null, even if in the database it's linked. I got these 2 models:

User:

```
[Table("users")]
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    [StringLength(15, MinimumLength =2)]
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("password")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Column("email")]
    [StringLength(30, MinimumLength =6)]
    [Required]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public List<UserActivityPoints> Activitypoints { get; set; }
}
```

UserActivityPoints:

```
[Table("activitypoints")]
public class UserActivityPoints
{
    [Key]
    [Column("type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [Column("amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("user_id")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

So, one thing that already was weird is, in the database, the `user_id` column becomes `UserId`, however it is correctly linked to the users, as shown below:

[A picture of PHPMyAdmin showing it's linked correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/koCaP.png)

In my database context, I have the following code:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserActivityPoints>().ToTable("activitypoints");
}
```

I run the following code:

```
var i = ProductionDbContext.GetInstance().Users.Find(1).Activitypoints;
```

I got a record shown in the following picture:

[The record is added in the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcWyF.png)

However, when I debug, `i` is always null, even though user 1 has a record in the activity points table. Am I doing something wrong or am I forgetting something?

Answer (score 0):

In `UserActivityPoints` you have `[Key]` above both `Type` and `UserId` - EFCore thinks you are trying to make the two combined into your primary key. Your `UserActivityPoints` should look like:

```
[Table("activitypoints")]
public class UserActivityPoints
{
    [Key]
    [Column("type")]
    public int Type { get; set; }

    [Column("amount")]
    public int Amount { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

I've removed the key, given you a column just for ID, and an object for User. Now it should work properly. Doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keys

Comment: Oh, the user_id and key should've been the composite key though. So I should just add an `id` column for the PK?

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize you meant to have the composite key. I've added it back in. I'm surprised it isn't working. I edited my response to distinctly map the foreign key (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships) and if that still doesn't work you may want to consider using the FluentAPI (https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/fluent-api-in-entity-framework-core.aspx).

Comment: I tried this: ```modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserActivityPoints>().ToTable("activitypoints").HasKey(a => new { a.Id, a.UserId });
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserActivityPoints>().HasOne(u => u.User).WithMany(a => a.Activitypoints).HasForeignKey(a => a.UserId);``` but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Okay so I did ```var i = ProductionDbContext.GetInstance().Users.Include(u => u.Activitypoints).First();``` and then the property wasn't null. But then I can't use .find with this. Is something changed in later versions of EF core where you need to load stuff yourself?

Comment: I'm not sure if it's changed but maybe the last project you worked on used a different type of loading? Doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data If `find` isn't working then please make a new question about that issue and what you are seeing! I've used `find` on related data in the past so maybe it is something I or someone else can help with :)

Comment: Actually I figured out include works. And include doesn't work for find, but only for queries. I will use LINQ and see if it is really that slow, and depending on that either make a new question or just use LINQ. Thanks for your help regardless!